Why does nothing show up in the Datastore database when using Google Cloud Functions?
I have set up a Google Cloud function that automatically runs a document AI processor when a document is uploaded to a storage bucket, and then sends the results to Datastore. I have created a database in "Datastore mode", but when i run my function nothing shows up in the Datastore database. No errors are caught in the log.
This is the code responsible for sending entities to the database:
    private static void InsertEntitiesToDatastore(DBObject tempDBObject)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("InsertEntitiesToDatastore");
        InsertInvoiceEntityToDatastore(tempDBObject.InvoiceObj, "Invoices");
        InsertItemsEntityToDatastore(tempDBObject.InvoiceObj.Store, tempDBObject.ItemsObj, "Items");
    }

    public static void InsertInvoiceEntityToDatastore(Invoice invoice, string invoiceKindName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("InsertInvoiceEntityToDatastore");
        var client = DatastoreDb.Create(projectId);

        var invoiceEntity = new DsEntity
        {
            Key = client.CreateKeyFactory(invoiceKindName).CreateIncompleteKey()
        };

        DateTime purchaseDateTime = invoice.Purchase_Date;
        if (purchaseDateTime.Kind != DateTimeKind.Utc)
        {
            purchaseDateTime = purchaseDateTime.ToUniversalTime();
        }
        Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.FromDateTime(purchaseDateTime);

        invoiceEntity["Purchase_Date"] = timestamp;
        invoiceEntity["SubTotal"] = invoice.SubTotal;
        invoiceEntity["Store"] = invoice.Store;
        client.Upsert(invoiceEntity);
        Console.WriteLine($"InsertInvoiceEntityToDatastore __ Upsert: {invoiceEntity}");
    }

    public static void InsertItemsEntityToDatastore(string Store, List<Item> items, string invoiceKindName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("InsertItemsEntityToDatastore");
        var client = DatastoreDb.Create(projectId);
        var itemEntities = new List<DsEntity>();
        var keyFactory = client.CreateKeyFactory(invoiceKindName);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            DsEntity dsEntity = new DsEntity
            {
                Key = keyFactory.CreateIncompleteKey()
            };
            dsEntity["Item_name"] = item.Item_name;
            dsEntity["Item_price"] = item.Item_price;
            dsEntity["Item_pant"] = item.Item_pant;
            dsEntity["Item_quantity"] = item.Item_quantity;
            dsEntity["Store"] = Store;
            itemEntities.Add(dsEntity);
        }
        client.Upsert(itemEntities);
    }

I am not very experienced with Google Cloud (it is my first time using it) so please let me now what information might be needed to solve this.
--
Edit:
This is the log with the first client.Upsert(Entity):
InsertInvoiceEntityToDatastore __ Upsert: { "key": { "partitionId": { "projectId": *projectID* }, "path": [ { "kind": "Invoices", "id": "5632499082330112" } ] }, "properties": { "Purchase_Date": { "timestampValue": "2024-02-29T00:00:00Z" }, "SubTotal": { "doubleValue": 77.30000305175781 }, "Store": { "stringValue": "REMA 1000 ELGESETER" } } }

And these are the IAM roles of the service account:


Please include logs. I suspect the Service Account (default Compute Engine?) that's the identity for your Cloud Functions function does not have permission (via its IAM roles) to operate on the Firestore database.

I updated the question with more information. I have used a custom service account on recommendation from this article.

It's been a minute since I used Datastore and I'm unfamiliar with the C# SDK. It certainly appears that the entity is being created. Does Upsert return a key? Are you confident that you're checking the correct database?

Another approach may be to wrap your Upsert's in a transaction as shown here

If you're new to Google Cloud, once this problem is solved, unless you've strong reasons to do use datastore mode, I'd encourage you to consider using Firestore in native mode.
